# Function not found when contained in script file and invoked from C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I am trying to invoke a powershell function contained in a script file from C#.
I am able to successfully invoke the function when it is a string variable, but when I try to invoke it from the script file, I get this error:

> The term 'Test-Me' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

What else is needed to invoke a script file function from C#?

```
public string RunScriptFunction(string userName)
{
    //var script = "function Test-Me($param1, $param2) { \"Hello from Test-Me with $param1, $param2\" }";
    var script = ". C:\\TestMe.ps1";
    using (var powershell = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        powershell.AddScript(script);
        var results1 = powershell.Invoke();
        powershell.Commands.Clear();

        powershell.AddCommand("Test-Me").AddParameter("param1", userName).AddParameter("param2", "HELLO");

        var results = powershell.Invoke();
        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (PSObject obj in results)
        {
            stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
        }
        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: try removing the . from `var script = ". C:\\TestMe.ps1"`

Comment: The '.' is needed, this is known as 'dot-sourcing' and is the old way of importing a PowerShell function (the new way would be to use modules btw)

Comment: I tried this already but it didn't help. I also tried to use global:funcName to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce your problem, which is that you cannot dot-source the PowerShell script due to the execution policy. Inspect the error in the  property `powershell.Streams.Error`. Its value will probably be:

> File C:\TestMe.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.

A possible solution in this case would be to set the ExecutionPolicy for the scope of your process before dot-sourcing your script:

```
var script = "Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process; . C:\\TestMe.ps1";
```